# ARM Template deploymentScripts custom container instance fileshare name

Tags: azure-rm-template

I have created a template which deploys a deploymentScripts to do some work in SQL. Since we locked down SQL on a network level I needed to create a custom container instance which is connected to my vnet. That Container Instance needs to have a volume mounted on an Azure Storage Account. The fileshare on that is created by the deploymentScripts deployment but you don't seem to be able to set that. How do I reliably get to that value so I can create that myself and mount? Here's the part of the container instance I'm talking about. Its the "shareName": "hvtqyj3nqhygoazscripts" I'm looking for. Seems to be using the uniqueString() function concatenated with 'azscripts'. What is the input to the uniqueString() function?

```json
"volumes": [
    {
        "name": "azscripts",
        "azureFile": {
            "shareName": "hvtqyj3nqhygoazscripts",
            "storageAccountName": "<storename>",
            "storageAccountKey": "<key>"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In DeploymentScripts (DS), ACI is not seen as a shared resource, so you cannot create it in advance and use it in DS (there's 1 ACI per DS), but you can use an existing Storage Account as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template#use-existing-storage-account). File shares are controlled by DS to isolate script content and outputs so you cannot control the name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Reading the docs again I found that I had mis-read the info on ACI. One can only specify the name, not assign an existing one as with storage. So, no custom ACI means no networking integration for DS? Is that part open-sourced? Would love to contribute and / or write the docs. Being able to assign a networking profile would suffice I think.

Comment: We have a work item to enable NetworkProfile on ACI, but is dependent upon ACI to enable this scenario: NetworkProfile + Managed Identity, which I know is on their roadmap. I'd say in ~6 months ACI will enable NetworkProfile + Managed Identity support, once it is supported we'll enable NetworkProfile in DeploymentScripts. The code is not open-sourced since is an Azure Service, but I'll let you know once the support is enabled.